Wordpress homepage returning error 404 code but the page is fine
My WordPress website's homepage, https://fandangoph.xyz is returning error 404 even the page is working. Other pages beside from homepage is working well and returning code 200.
I tried all troubleshooting methods I saw in the internet like clearing cache in cloudflare and from my server.
The last thing I did is by putting this code in my WordPress website, but the issue still persists:
<?php
    include('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

Is there any way to fix this? I spend a whole day figuring it out but no luck.
Server: Linode (Ubuntu)
Webserver: Openlitespeed
CDN: Cloudflare

I have gone through the website and the site is visible on my end. If you are using Cloudflare, please consider clearing cache. You can also disable caching until you are done with development.
After development, consider versioning your code to ensure it does not load an  older version of the site.
For error 404, confirm that the file, wp-blog-header.php, is in the blog directory of the project.
